# How create and keep POJO in SessionScope

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, session-scope

I have app with J2EE, EJB 3.0 and JSF. My session are been used with JSFSession. I want store user data in EJB that I can read and write in any point of my app (EJB, ManagedBean, Interceptor). Any idea?
THX

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but if your data is not user specific, you should probably use @stateless Bean

Comment: But in @Stateless I can´t save data in session for after use